# How to pdflatex with CJK characters/font/encoding

Tags: pdf, unicode, latex, pdflatex, cjk

What's the best way to combine pdflatex with CJK characters/font/encoding?

I'd like to generate pdf that includes CJK characters, and in the future all possible unicode characters.

I'm thinking about using  'The CJK package for LaTeX' for cjk characters specifically but it seems not to be maintained since 2006.

Can you suggest something better?

Comment: Is using XeLaTeX out of the question?

Comment: This is an unknown, as I'm using a package which works with pdflatex, and not latex itself. I'd rather stick with pdflatex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I upgraded to the last version of tex-live (the 2009 vintage) and all is fine with pdfpages/xelatex

I can now work in full UTF-8/unicode and use my favorite ttf and otf fonts.